# DNS Packet (Header, Requests, Responses) How To Parse

Tags: dns, header, packet

What is the best way to parse an DNS Response Stream.

The DNS Packet is splitted into 3 parts.

DNS Header DNS Requests DNS Responses

To Parse each file is easy. But how do i know where each parts are splitted. There is no seperator.

43bf8100000100010000000003777777076773746174696303636f6d0000010001c00c000100010000003c0004acd91663

43bf81000001000100000000 (Header)

03777777076773746174696303636f6d0000010001 (Requests)

c00c000100010000003c0004acd91663 (Responses)

See here: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSMessageHeaderandQuestionSectionFormat.htm

When i have multiple Answers or maybe questions. How do i know where to seperate the request section from the response section?

Cheers

Comment: You need to start by reading RFC 1034 and 1035 multiple times. Pay specific attention to name compression, as this is (was) the source of many bugs. Alternatively, all major programming languages have DNS libraries that are able to parse and generate DNS packets so why go the trouble of reinventing the wheel ( if you have reasons to do so, you didn't specify them)

Comment: And you can not have multiple questions, this would be against the DNS specifications. You can have multiple answers indeed, as well as for the authority and additional sections.